# meaning of 'dispersion' in Tune function in R

Tags: r, svm, cross-validation

I checked the internet and the R documentation to find the meaning of 'dispersion' in the output of the following function:

```
tune(
    svm, 
    Purchase ~ ., 
    data = OJ.train, 
    kernel = "linear", 
    ranges = list(cost = 10^seq(-2, 1, by = 0.25)))
```

I could not find an understandable meaning for 'dispersion'. Would someone please explain what it does?

Following is a code that you can check for this question:

```
library(ISLR)
set.seed(1)
train <- sample(nrow(OJ), 800)
OJ.train <- OJ[train, ]
OJ.test <- OJ[-train, ]

library(e1071)
tune.out <- tune(
    svm, 
    Purchase ~ ., 
    data = OJ.train, 
    kernel = "linear", 
    ranges = list(cost = 10^seq(-2, 1, by = 0.25)))
summary(tune.out)
```

Comment: `dispersion` is neither a parameter of `tune` nor of `svm`. What are you asking? Can you please provide reproducible code and details/output to clarify?

Comment: I said, it will be shown as an output of function 'tune'. Sorry using word 'parameter' in last sentence was a mistake. Will share the reproducible code soon.

Comment: what OP means is one of the performance parameters(columns) in the outupt. The source code for `tune` has a statement `cbind(parameters, 
            error = model.errors, dispersion = model.variances)` .  Someone can probably throw some light on that.

Comment: @user3665906 Thanks for the clarification; great reprex! This seems to be a duplicate question of [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/366380/error-and-dispersion-meaning-in-tune-out-for-svm-classifier) on Cross Validated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [Error and Dispersion meaning in tune.out for SVM Classifier](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/366380/error-and-dispersion-meaning-in-tune-out-for-svm-classifier), but since I can't flag CV questions as SO duplicates, here is short summary.

1. Details on the meaning of dispersion can be found in `?tune.control`.
2. By default `dispersion` corresponds to the standard deviation of the aggregated training results based on the training data. You can change that by explicitly defining functions for `sampling.aggregate` and `sampling.disperion` in `tune.control`.